# Use a list of same values to select rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3], 'Age': [20, 21, 22]})
df

   Id  Age
0   1   20
1   2   21
2   3   22
```

Now, I want to find rows in which the `Id` are 1 and 2. In this case, I use the following code:

```
df.loc[df.Id.isin([1, 2])]
```

and it returns:

```
   Id  Age
0   1   20
1   2   21
```

When I use two same `Id`, it returns only one row. For example when I use the following code:

```
df.loc[df.Id.isin([1, 1])]
```

it returns:

```
   Id  Age
0   1   20
```

My desired output in this case is:

```
   Id  Age
0   1   20
1   1   20
```

How can I get this output only using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Id` as the index, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), and reset `Id` back to a column:

```
df.set_index('Id').loc[[1, 1]].reset_index()

#    Id  Age
# 0   1   20
# 1   1   20
```